# Globe Software Atlas Error: AtlasTable function "Failed to build Atlas forumla"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We have an Atlas Template (Excel document) containing a number of formulas.  One of these formulas is causing the exception message:

> Failed to build Atlas formula: =AtlasTable("Production Support",$C$3,"T.CCFRAR_LedgerTransExtended","%VendInvoice","","","","","","","AccountNum|Voucher",$G12,$P12))
>   Column output field: Field 'VendInvoice' not found in table 'CCFRAR_LedgerTransExtended' (Production)

[image: Atlas 5.1 Error Message Screenshot]

NB: Production Support is the name of a test environment - exactly the same exception is displayed if used in Production, only the formula is changed from reading `Production Support` to `Production`.

The table `CCFRAR_LedgerTransExtended` does contain a column called `VendInvoice` (this is the name when viewed through the AOT and also when viewed in SQL directly).

Exactly the same formula works if I replace `%VendInvoice` with `%DocumentNum` or `%VendAccount` (e.g. other column names from the same table).

The table `CCFRAR_LedgerTransExtended` is a customization,  but this table has existed for a long time (i.e. more than 1 year, with no changes to its definition).

The AOT is synchronised with the database, and both AOS and Atlas Service have been restarted, with all caches being flushed.

Has anyone got any thoughts on what may be causing Atlas to not see this column?

Comment: NB: Question also posted to Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/675523/globe-software-atlas-error-atlastable-function-failed-to-build-atlas-forumla

Comment: Not sure if this is a good stack question since Atlas is a 3rd party product...

Comment: @AlexK: Agreed; I started in Super User, but no luck on there / there's not even an AX tag, so thought I'd try my luck here (as it falls into one of the gray areas between forums).  Will leave it here for a bit on the off chance someone with Atlas experience is here, but will remove if it stagnates / will update the superuser one with an answer once we solve it.  Thanks.

Comment: A simple question, but are you able to see the field if you use that table as a data source in a journal/table upload? IF so, are you able to upload sample data to that field in the testing environment?

Comment: @Pnuts: Yes, copied and pasted with no luck.  I also tried playing the the case of the fields which were working to see if Atlas was case sensitive - it worked regardless.  Good shout though.  All field names are alphanumeric with no unusual characters or spaces.

Comment: @KingOfZeal: Tried but failed - regardless of what method I use, those fields don't appear to be visible to Atlas.  Outside of Atlas (e.g. checking the database and SqlDictionary table directly or looking via AOT) they are listed as expected though.

Comment: Since Atlas is not aware of that field in any way, are there any odd properties set for the field in AX (Visible = No, Configuration Key that isn't enabled, etc)? If not, I would contact Globe directly -- they do tend to have good user support, and this could be an (admittedly strange) bug. I have never seen this behavior myself.

Comment: @kingofzeal: Nothing unusual about the field so far as I can see.  A colleague's got a call open with our partner (who will be in contact with Globe), so I'll wait to see what they come back with - was asking on here in case it was something that someone had seen before / could provide a quick answer to.  Thanks again all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred when we were running Atlas 5.1.3491.

On both Atlas Client (TS/RD Server) and Atlas Service Server I did the following:

1. I ran a repair (control panel, programs & features, Atlas, Change, Repair) which uninstalled Atlas then crashed with an error saying it couldn't find Atlas.40.Resources (or similar).
2. I then downloaded the latest version of Atlas (5.1.3558) from Globe (http://globesoftware.com/Resources/Download-Atlas-5-1).
3. I ran the install for this version as Admin

After the above I restarted the services, logged into Atlas and retested - all worked correctly.